# Handsontableでカラムをクリックした時のデフォルトのソート順を降順にしたい

Tags: javascript

[Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/demo/sorting.html)で`columnSorting:true`にしておくとカラムのヘッダーをクリックした時に昇順ソート、再クリックで降順ソートになりますが、これを最初のクリックを降順、再クリックで昇順のように変更することはできますか？

※追記

初期表示状態でのソート順を下記のように指定できることはわかったのですが、

```
var hot = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('grid'), {
  columnSorting: {
    column: 3,
    sortOrder: false // 降順
  }
});
```

このような指定でもカラムヘッダーをクリックした場合は昇順→降順の動作になります。

ソースをカスタマイズするしかないのでしょうか…

Answer (score 3):

自己解決しました。

ソースを追っかけてみたところ、API的に設定できる感じではなさそうだったので、ソースをカスタマイズすることで対応しました。

```
this.setSortingColumn = function (col, order) {
  var instance = this;

  if (typeof col == 'undefined') {
    delete instance.sortColumn;
    delete instance.sortOrder;

    return;
  } else if (instance.sortColumn === col && typeof order == 'undefined') {
    instance.sortOrder = !instance.sortOrder;
  } else {
    // instance.sortOrder = typeof order != 'undefined' ? order : true; // ここを
    instance.sortOrder = typeof order != 'undefined' ? order : false; // falseにする
  }

  instance.sortColumn = col;
};
```

Handsontable 0.12.2 8857行目のsetSortingColumnの定義のところです。

Comment: Pull Request 投げてしまうとよいかもしれないですね。